# Python module Wikipedia producing the wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia

**Code**

```
QUESTION=input("") #Albert Einstein
RESULTS = wikipedia.search(str(QUESTION))#['einstein family', 'hans albert einstein', 'albert einstein', 'religious and philosophical views of albert einstein', "albert einstein's brain", 'albert einstein house', 'elsa einstein', 'albert einstein memorial', 'albert einstein college of medicine', 'bernhard caesar einstein']
for i in range(len(RESULTS)):
    print(RESULTS[i])#einstein family
    RESULT = wikipedia.summary(str(RESULTS[i]))#PAGE ID "EPSTEIN FAMILY" DOES NOT MATCH ANY PAGES. TRY ANOTHER ID!
```

It for some reason changes einstein family to epstein family and i have no idea why does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions must ask a specific question. Your question simply declares that you have no idea why this happens, and while the "how do I fix it?" is implied, it is better to ask that explicitly. Thanks for figuring this out and posting an answer though! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the

```
RESULT = wikipedia.summary(str(RESULTS[i]))
```

to

```
RESULT = wikipedia.summary(str(RESULTS[i]), auto_suggest=False)
```

I was looking through the `wikipedia.py` file and found that `auto_suggest` can change your `RESULTS[i]` to a close approximation and so by turning it to `False` it stops that and gives me the correct answer.

As for the details, please check [Wikipedia API](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).